# Как передать данные в поток из активности?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Есть инициализация *блютуз-сервиса*, где запущен поток, который проверяет, не пустая ли очередь для отправки сообщений.

После инициализации я вызываю из *мэйн-активити* другую *активность*, где уже осуществляется ввод данных, которые необходимо передать.

Есть ли какие-нибудь способы передать данные из неосновной *активности* в этот поток, не передавая сам объект класса *блютуз-сервиса*?

Answer (score 1):

Если Ваш *блютуз-сервис* это реальный Service в понятиях Андроид, то что мешает ему послать Intent с данными?

```
Context.startService (Intent service)
```

не запускает повторно уже запущеный сервис, а вызывает его метод

```
onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

А там сервис дожен знать как передать потоку, который он создал, данные из интента.